# Store a text in encrypted form and use in powershell script without compromising it to other users?

Tags: powershell

I want to encrypt a text which I want to use in different PowerShell script without compromising its security as other user will be using scripts that will contain that text. Basically I want to conceal that text from everybody and use it without any hassle to all PowerShell scripts that are using that particular text.

Please visit this link for more details as I asked this question to stackoverflow and they suggested me to ask here.

[Original Question Please Open this for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801713/store-a-text-in-encrypted-form-and-use-in-powershell-script-without-compromising)

Comment: So you want text which is encrypted, but without providing a decryption key, your scripts can read? You'd be best off bringing the key details into your question here, to minimise the chances of someone trying to answer without reading them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the plain text, this is impossible.

The best you can do is to obfuscate the text, e.g. to make it harder for someone to get at it, but as stated in the original question, even if you encrypt the text, you'll need to store the decryption key somewhere, so this just adds one more complication to a determined attacker.

It will be the same with all other ideas you think up to protect the text - it can't be done, whether you use Powershell scripts or something else.